# Reading in RAW image is larger

Tags: python

When I read in a camera raw image (CR2) via rawpy it is larger then the original and was wondering if anyone knows what the issue might be. The original image is of size 6000 by 4000, but comes in as 6022 by 4020.

```py
with rawpy.imread(raw_image) as raw:
    img = raw.postprocess(output_bps=16, output_color=rawpy.ColorSpace.sRGB)

print(img.shape)  # -> (6022, 4020, 3)
```

Comment: Camera sensors include extra pixels on the borders that are intended for black level detection and algorithms that require extra overreach.  Those pixels are cropped when generating a JPEG.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading it with scikit-image. If the shape is the same as with rawpy, then it might be due to the extra pixels mentioned by [Mark Ransom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom). If the shape is correct, then the extra pixels were due to the camera sensor and you can now use the image as a numpy array (or try reading it via the rawpy library).

Last but not least, you could try [opencv](https://opencv.org), which can read camera images in real time.

## Scikit-image

https://scikit-image.org/